# C++ Program Debugging

Tags: c++

I seem to be having some problems with my program. It compiles fine, but when I get to my first loop it asks me for a positive integer than it asks me again like its suppose too. Than it hops down a blank space and wont run any further until you enter another number which its not suppose to do. But than when you enter a number it goes back and asks me to enter an integer also like its suppose to the problem is, IT will do this infinite amount of times until I quit the program. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
/* Search the entries of the n X n matrix mat in rowwise order for an entry to item */
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)

{ 

int n=10, item, row=3, col=3, mat[row][col];
bool found;

for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
                cout << "Enter Positive Integer :  ";
                        cin >> row;
                cout << " Enter Positive Integer : ";
                cin >> mat[row][col];
        }

cout << "Enter a positive integer you want to be searched: ";
        cin >> item;


for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
{
     for(int j=0; j<col; ++j)
     {
          if(mat[row][col] == item)
              found = true;
          else
               found = false;
     }  
}

if(found==true)
  cout << "item found" ;
else
    cout << "item found ";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Third time with the same question?

Comment: Youre matrix `mat` is the right size. In your forloop you loop from (0 to 4) while your matrix is of size 3. Change `row=3,col=3` to `row=5,col=5`

Comment: Well I got it to compile now at least

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Third time's the charm, but three's a crowd.  So confusing...

Comment: First, learn to format code so it's readable. Then, learn to use a debugger to step through the code and see when it does something it shouldn't (like changing `row` during the first loop, or setting `found` to `false` after finding the value, or printing "found" when it wasn't found). Then, figure out why it did that and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

The line `for (int cols = 0; cols < 5; col++)` increments the variable `col`, not `cols`. Since `cols` is always 0, the loop will never terminate.

You've done the same in `for (int rows = 0; rows < 5; row++)`. Infinite loops often occur due to typos in loop conditions ;)

I would also like to point out some logic errors during your search:

```
for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
{
     for(int j=0; j<col; ++j)
     {
          if(mat[row][col] == item)
              found = true;
          else
               found = false;
    }  
}
```

When that loop ends, `found` will only be `true` if `mat[row-1][col-1] == item` (the very last element). Heck, `row` and `col` never change in the loop so you are repeatedly checking the exact same element every time! You should also expect even more funky program behavior if you don't get a grasp on your variable names. I strongly recommend adding debug statements to see how your variables are being modified throughout the program (aka: `cout << "rows = " << rows << endl;`, and `cout << "i = " << i << endl;`, etc). You're preparing a recipe for disaster when you reuse your variables.

**Disclaimer:** Reusing variables is not always a bad thing. However, it's best to avoid it until you have a stronger understanding of variables.

Comment: yes I edited all that thank you, except its still doing the same thing

Comment: You changed `col++` to `cols++` and `row++` to `rows++`? You should be asked 9 pairs of questions (3 x 3).

Comment: Thank you!! except now its not even acknowledging the first for loop is even there. its skipping right down and asking me what integer do i want to search for

Comment: Its only asking me the question twice

Comment: When you're given a solution, it's important to understand why and how the solution works. The reason your loop is skipping down is due to another typo in your loop. See if you can find it.

Comment: I see you've since made minor changes to your loop. However, those changes now cause the program to overwrite your loop counter (col) with `cin >> col;`. A good early coding practice is to *never* modify the for-loop counter inside of the loop itself.

Comment: im guessing it has something to do with how im reading in the data

Comment: No, it's not how you're reading in the data, it's the fact that you're reading the data into variables that are already in use (see comment by @CollinJSimpson)

Comment: Okay I understand why i don't need that first cin >> col; because immediately after that statement I am reading in a number for col. Thank you! Now I am going to finish up fixing the last end of my code

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are incrementing `row` and `col` not `rows` and `cols`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using the *same* variable for the loop counter and the user input storage. That is doomed to not do what you want.
Do something like:

```
for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 3; rowCounter++) {
    for (colCounter = 0; colCounter < 3; colCounter++) {
        cout << “Give me value for (“ << rowCounter << “,” << colCounter << “) :”;
        cin >> mat[rowCounter][colCounter];
    }
}
```

and then the rest of your code

Comment: And then in your search loop, you want to use if (mat[i][j] == item) rather than mat[row][col], since i and j are your iteration indices now rather than row and col

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had a couple of issues.

1. In the first for loop, you were incrementing the wrong variable (col instead of cols), you also went from 0 to 4 in a 3x3 matrix
2. you asked the user for 2 numbers then you asked the user to put in a number in the       matrix, but its only a 3x3 matrix, the user could easy go out of bounds. I think what you were trying to do was populate the matrix with users number. So i made that change.
3. In the second for loop, you set found =true, but the loop will keep going, meaning the last number it searched, if it was false, then found = false, also changed it to mat[i][j] instead of mat[row][col], so it doesn't check the same one every time.
4. both found = true and found = false would return "item found", i think you left off the "not" in the second hard coded string.
5. I added a pause so you can read the output at the end.

I fixed them and I think this code should do what you want it to now.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)

{ 

  int n=10, item, row = 3, col = 3;
  int mat[3][3];
  bool found = false;
  int j,k;

  for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
      for (int cols = 0; cols < 3; cols++)
      {
            cout << "Enter row Integer: ";
            cin >>j;
            cout << "Enter col Integer: ";
            cin >> k;
            cout << "Enter Positive Integer :  ";
            cin >> mat[j][k];
      }

  cout << "Enter a poistive integer you want to be searched: ";
  cin >> item;


  int flag = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
  {
     for(int j=0; j<col; ++j)
     {
        if(mat[i][j] == item)
        {
            flag = flag + 1;
        }
     }  
  }

  if(flag > 0)
   found = true;

  if(found==true)
  cout << "item found" ;
  else
  {
     cout << "item not found ";
  }

   system("PAUSE");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is it that you have fixed

Comment: @LaggKing, Give a man a fish, he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime, no?

Comment: You're right @CollinJSimpson. Looking back at the mistakes, its clear its a newcomer learning and not someone stuck on a difficult problem. I hope he uses it to see his mistakes and not just copiest.

Comment: how does this
            cout << "Enter Positive Integer :  ";
            cin >> mat[rows][cols];   collect the input for row and col though

Comment: @user2748096, it doesn't to do that you would have to replace it with the code i just edited so its easier to see.

Though i really don't recommend it, since the user can put in an integer that is out of the array bounds.